# iOS Information Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, button

On a number of iPhone applications I'm seeing a little blue circular button that, when clicked on, displays information about the application. Is this something that is built into the iOS SDK, or is it simply a custom button with a custom image?

Comment: You should accept one of these answers and close this question.

Answer (score 30):

You can make an info button in Interface Builder by placing a button (a Rounded Button) and changing its type into dark or light info button.

You can also crate an info button programmatically like this:

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
```

Answer (score 5):

It's in the Interface Builder. Place a Round-Rect button and change the type to "Info Light" or "Info Dark"

Then you simply link it to creating a new subview in which you place all the information about the app or whatever else you would like to put there.

Answer (score 4):

- Yes, it is built into the SDK.
- Place a button in interface builder and choose `info dark` and `info
  light` from the button types in the attributes inspector.

Is this the button?

[image: screenshot of view]

It is available in dark gray and light gray only.. if it is not.. Please post a link to which button you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an info button in Interface Builder by placing a button (a Rounded Button) and changing its type into dark or light info button.